# How to inject new block in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working on custom module and try to embed my custom module block code on cms block during loading time. My code for block is:

```
{{block type="module/block_name" categories="2,4,3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" }}
```

This runs on cms block page. But I am trying to embed the block code during run time. For this I create an event

```
 <events>
     <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
          <observers>
              <mypage>
                       <type>singleton</type>
                       <class>Module_Model_Observer</class>
                       <method>addlisttocms</method>
                </mypage>
         </observers>
     </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
</events>
```

While on observer I create function :

```
public function addlisttocms(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
     $controller = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
     $layout = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
     $var = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
     $page =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('page_id');
}
```

Now I want that when the cms page load, I embed my block using above function. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use layout XML or a custom widget to do this.

Custom module layout XML file:

```
<cms_page_view>
    <block name="some.block" type="module/block_name" parent="content" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategories">
            <ids>2,3,4</ids>
        </action>
    </block>
</cms_page_view>
```

Comment: can you provide little more detailed answer.?

Comment: Done, on my phone, so a bit short.

Comment: Sorry but if you see my question i want to add this block code in observer not in xml.I am trying such code $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addUpdate() to add my block dynamically.Hope you got my point.

Comment: I do not understand your point. Why are you doing / must you do this  with an observer? Every block in the layout could work this way as well. There's a reason they don't.

Comment: The reason is i am getting ids dynamically, while in xml i think i can't do that.If you know in xml update me it will be a nice choice for me.

Comment: I don't see how your block is getting those IDs dynamically from the observer code you posted. The Magento convention for MVC is to allow blocks to invoke collections classes internally rather than couple multiple layers together. For the example you posted, your block could contain a `_construct()` method which uses `$this->getRequest()` to accomplish the same thing. Further, by using the event you chose, your block will *never* be part of layout XML cache; both are considerations to be aware of.

Comment: i am following this post http://asia-connect.com.vn/2009/07/magento-filter-by-multiple-categories/.while ids i set from observer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21822/discussion-between-benmarks-and-mahmood-rehman)

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer.change event to 'controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before' and in observer inject code like

```
  $layout = $observer->getLayout();
 $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<reference name="content"> 
    <block name="mymodule" type="mymodule/blockname"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategories">
            <ids>2,3,4</ids>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>');
$layout->generateXml();.
```

For refrence check the [site](http://prattski.com/2012/04/25/magento-more-flexibility-for-your-layout-updates/).